# How to change ActionForward with dynamic params in Struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, migration, struts, actionresult

While migrating the application from Struts 1 to Struts 2

In some of the places, the same action class has been used for different type of views, based on the request params.

For example: if the `createType` is 1 means need to append one param or if the `createType` is 2 means need to append some more extra params, like that I need to pass dynamic params to some other action using `ActionForward`.

**`struts-config.xml`:**

```xml
<action path="/CommonAction" type="com.example.CommonAction" scope="request">
    <forward name="viewAction" path = "/ViewAction.do"/>
</action>
```

**Action class:**

```
public class CreateAction extends Action
{
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping m, ActionForm f, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, Exception
    {
            String actionPath = m.findForward("viewAction").getPath();
            String createType = req.getParameter("createType");
            String params = "&action=view";
            if("1".equals(createType)){
               params = params + "&from=list";
            }else if("2".equals(createType)){
               params = params + "&from=detail&someParam=someValue";
            }//,etc..
            String actionUrl = actionPath+"?"+params;
            return new ActionForward(actionUrl);
    }
}
```

But, I not able to do the same thing in Struts 2. Is there any possibilities to change `ActionForward` with dynamic params in Struts 2 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a dynamic parameters with a `result`, see the [dynamic result configuration](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/result-configuration.html#dynamic-results).

In the action you should write a getter for the patrameter

```
private String actionUrl;

public String getActionUrl() {
    return actionUrl;
}
```

and configure result

```
<action name="create" class="CreateAction">
    <result type="redirect">${actionUrl}</result>
</action>
```

So, the common sense would be rewrite the code like

```
public class CreateAction extends ActionSupport
{

    private String actionUrl;

    public String getActionUrl() {
        return actionUrl;
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception
    {
            String actionPath = "/view";
            String createType = req.getParameter("createType");
            String params = "&action=view";
            if("1".equals(createType)){
               params = params + "&from=list";
            }else if("2".equals(createType)){
               params = params + "&from=detail&someParam=someValue";
            }//,etc..
            actionUrl = actionPath+"?"+params;
            return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

If you need a better way to create the urls from action mapping, you could look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449117/struts-2-sending-mail-with-embedded-url/17451525#17451525) answer.

Comment: In Struts 1, It won't redirect unless we use redirect param as true [ new ActionForward(path,redirect) ]. But in Struts 2 as you suggested its always redirecting as a new Action. How to avoid this in Struts 2 ?

Comment: Redirect is a normal deal with the action. Are you sure you want to forward to the action?

Comment: A new Action object is always created upon request, do you want to avoid it?

Comment: I don't want to get as a new request from browser, simply I want internal action forward.

Comment: Then you should configure struts filter to accept forward requests from dispatcher.

Comment: Do you have any reference for that.

Comment: [This example is for sitmesh](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs//sitemesh-plugin.html#SiteMeshPlugin-FullintegrationwithSiteMesh2Freemarker2.4.2Velocity1.3,includingStruts2Tags,ValueStack,andFreemarkerManagerstatics.). Or look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119925/how-to-forward-request-from-servlet-to-action-of-struts2) question and answers.