# Struts 2 JSON plugin and wildcard issue

Tags: java, json, struts2, wildcard, struts2-json-plugin

In my `struts.xml` a convention is followed to call actions for a particular action class like this:

**`struts.xml`:**

```xml
<package name="cdot.oss.cmsat.gma.struts" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
    <action name="*ConfigureTspThreshold"
                class="cdot.oss.cmsat.gma.struts.ConfigureTspThresholdAction" method="{1}">
                <result name="display">pages/ConfigureTspThresholdInput.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

I get method name through wildcard and `ConfigureTspThresholdAction` is the class name.

I am using `struts2-json-plugin` to convert data to JSON. Now, for some actions I want to return JSON data using Struts2 JSON plugin.

So I need to use extends `json-default` and result-type `json` for some actions like this:

```xml
<action name="*ConfigureTspThreshold" class="cdot.oss.cmsat.gma.struts.ConfigureTspThresholdAction" method="{1}">               
    <result type="json">
        <param name="excludeProperties">
            tspNameIdMap
        </param>
    </result>
</action>

<action name="*ConfigureTspThreshold" class="cdot.oss.cmsat.gma.struts.ConfigureTspThresholdAction"
            method="{1}">
    <result type="json">
        <param name="excludeProperties">
        thresholdParameters
        </param>
    </result>
</action>
```

So different exclude-properties with same result-type `json` .

How to fit these JSON result types in the convention followed?

As the last two actions will conflict as they have same result type `json` ?

Comment: Put different results inside your action and return different result codes from method.

Comment: @AleksandrM: result has to be JSON. I didn't get you. Can u elaborate or explain through some code ???

Comment: How do you determine which property needs to be excluded?

Comment: This question is not clear *at all*. Please edit it, explain exactly what you want and which problems you encountered while trying to achieve it. It's hard to answer a question without actually knowing the question.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is create a property in your action class `myexcludedProperties`

And then in your action methods, set this `myexcludedProperties`

and then change your action mapping to

```
<action name="*ConfigureTspThreshold" class="cdot.oss.cmsat.gma.struts.ConfigureTspThresholdAction"
            method="{1}">
            <result type="json">
                <param name="excludeProperties">
                    ${myexcludedProperties}
                </param>
            </result>
</action>
```

I believe `${myexcludedProperties}` is the correct syntax.

If you don't want to code a property, you have to figure out how to differentiate requests (`method="{1}"`) so that you can set the correct param.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

One of the option is to use dynamic parameters in the result configuration. You can always modify the result in the action before result is executed. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17838591/573032) answer.

> You could use a dynamic parameters with a result, see the [dynamic result](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/result-configuration.html#dynamic-results) configuration.
>
> In the action you should write a getter for the patrameter
>
> ```
> private String actionUrl;
>
> public String getActionUrl() {
>    return actionUrl;
> }
> ```
>
> and configure result
>
> ```
> <action name="create" class="CreateAction">
>    <result type="redirect">${actionUrl}</result>
> </action>
> ```